# solving a recurrence equation $T(n) = T(cn) + T((1-c)n) + 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

first, this question has been asked here before, however I have some issues with it that haven't been answered yet :

give asymptotic bounds of $\ T(n) \ $ where

> $ T(n) = T(cn)+ T((1-c)n) +1 , \ 0<c<1 $

this is the original post [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723596/tn-tcn-t1-cn1-while-0c1)
I didn't quite understand why the answer given over there was with a linear solution $S(n) = nS(1)$

and another thing, I've been told by someone that an even tighter bound is $\theta(log(n))$ is possible.

so two things, is this true, and why is the linear solution is of the form given before.

thanks ahead.

Comment: The title has $+1$ on the rhs, the body has $+n$. The [Akra–Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) is applicable to both cases, giving $p = 1$.

Comment: It’s suppose to be +1